# _crtisvalidheappointer error when trying to free memory

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation

I get _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData) error when running the code above.
Sometimes the code works perfectly, and sometimes this message appears. So I guess the problem is related to the memory allocation. But I've gone through the code many times and the numbers make sence to me (and also when debugging).
I noticed it happens in line "free(str_temp)" at the debugging.

The relevant code is here:

```
 int main(){

int n;
int len;
char *str;
char command[3];

printf("Enter your string:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
str = malloc(n+1);
scanf("%s", str);

while (1){

    printf(">");
    scanf("%s", command);


    if (compare(command, "ml")) {
        int k;
        scanf("%d", &k);
        multiply(str, n, k);
        printf("Current string is %s\n", str);
        n = ln(str);
        continue;

    }


free(str);
return 0;
}



void multiply(char *str, int n, int k) {

char *str_temp = malloc(n+1);
int i;
int j;
int q;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    str_temp[i] = str[i];
}
str_temp[n] = '\0';

free(str);
*str = malloc(n*k+1);
for (i = 0; i < k; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        str[i*n + j] = str_temp[j];
    }
}
str[n*k] = '\0';

free(str_temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use message defination

```
void multiply(char **str, int n, int k)//Use **str(double pointer) instead of *str.
```

And call it like

```
multiply(&str, n, k);
```